# Why `Monad` is required to use `pure`?

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell with [Luis Morillo's Haskell challenge for beginners (snake-fury)](https://github.com/lsmor/snake-fury/).
One of the tasks in [exercise 4](https://github.com/lsmor/snake-fury/blob/main/exercises/refactor-4.md) is "to implement `Applicative` instance for the new type" where the new type is the following:

```hs
newtype GameStep m a = GameStep {runGameStep :: ReaderT BoardInfo (StateT GameState m) a}
```

Here is my first attempt, which did not compile.

```hs
instance (Applicative m) => Applicative (GameStep m) where
  pure a = GameStep $ pure a
  (GameStep r) <*> (GameStep s) = GameStep $ r <*> s
```

GHC says

```
    • Could not deduce (Monad m) arising from a use of ‘pure’
      from the context: Applicative m
        bound by the instance declaration at src/GameState.hs:55:10-52
      Possible fix:
        add (Monad m) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            pure :: forall a. a -> GameStep m a
          or the instance declaration
```

(and same for `<*>` use)

It compiles if I replace `(Applicative m) => ...` with `(Monad m) => ...` as suggested. However, I do not understand this error message because `pure` (as well as `<*>`) is defined for `Applicative`, not for `Monad`.

Why does `Monad` require `pure`?

Comment: You can derive the instances with GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving: `deriving newtype (Functor, Applicative, Alternative, Monad, MonadPlus, MonadFail, MonadIO, Contravariant)` or unfolding the definition and deriving via the monad stack: `newtype GameStep m a = GameStep (BoardInfo -> GameState -> m (a, GameState)) deriving .. via ReaderT BoardInfo (StateT GameState m)`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's because your `m` is wrapped inside of `StateT` (and then in `ReaderT`, but that doesn't add anything).

When you write `GameStep $ pure a`, that `pure a` must return not just `m a`, but `ReaderT _ (StateT _ m) a`

And if you look at [the docs for `StateT`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-22.3/transformers-0.6.1.0/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#t:StateT), you'll see that `Applicative` is defined as:

```
instance (Functor m, Monad m) => Applicative (StateT s m)
```

So it's not your own instance that requires `Monad`, it's the one of `StateT`.

---

Now, the *reason* `StateT` requires `Monad` is that, in order to implement `<*>`, it needs to execute both arguments, but for `StateT` the order of execution matters, because each execution potentially modifies the state. So `StateT`'s implementation of `<*>` has to use the underlying `Monad`'s implementation of `>>=` to define the order in which the arguments are executed and thread the state between them.

Comment: Wow, thank you @fyodor-soikin.  If I remove `StateT` from the definition like `newtype GameStep m a = GameStep {runGameStep :: ReaderT BoardInfo m a}`, it indeed compiles.  The compiler is so smart that it infers constraints from `runGameStep`.